# PHP User Access Control - Check on Page_Load

Tags: php, .net

I am working on a the backend of a website. It is already working, and everything is in place, but I recently built a user management section. Now I would like to create user rights for users, and only allow those who are set as administrators on the database to access the user management pages.

I had done something with .NET which has a very nice authentication feature, and on page load I check if the user is authorised to access this page, if not redirect him to an access denied page. Is there something similar for PHP? Which would get the username of the user logged in and check it with the database, if he is allowed he would see the website, otherwise he gets redirected to an access denied page.

If there is a better solution, please feel free to post it here!

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what you need the system to handle. Most PHP-based authenication systems use session variables and MySql to store and keep active user information available to the application. I've never used this, but [SUMO](http://sumoam.sourceforge.net/) is apparently an easy to implement authentication system. It's also relatively easy to build a basic user authentication/permissions system with PHP. A google search will bring up thousands of tutorials.

Comment: I am trying something out with Session at the moment, because I've figured out if only I can store which group that user belongs to, I can then use the group as authentication

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic(for-starter) example:

In every page(place this a the top: line:1) that requires authentication:

```
<?php
  session_start();
  //check if login key is already present, if yes user is already login
  if(!isset($_SESSION['login']) {
    header('location: login.php'); //redirect to login page
  }

  //sample of accessing a session variable
  echo "current user is ", $_SESSION['username'];
?>
```

On login page:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    //check if user credentials
    if(username and password) {
         //set a marker on the session
         $_SESSION['login'] = true;
         $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
         //place additional info on the session
    }
?>
```

On you logout page:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    unset($_SESSION['login']);
    //or $_SESSION = array(); //clears all session variables
?>
```